# Changing the db and table that laravel looks at for auth

Tags: php, laravel

We are migrating a PHP app over to laravel and we already have a database.

I followed the instructions and modified config/auth.php users provider to be:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
                'driver' => 'database',
                'table' => 'our_database.user_auth_data',
        ],
    ],
```

When I try to register or auth a new user it says:

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_key' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `user_key` = bsemailaddress@yahoo.com) "

Why is it still trying to use the laravel.users table when I explicitly told it not to?

Comment: have you verified if your `users` table have a model in you laravel application?

Comment: check your users table/column and update your query with correct column name (if custom query)

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear your config cache after any modification in config file

here is command

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Did this, unfortunately it's still looking at the 'users' table that we aren't using.

Comment: I deleted the database information out of .env (its in the database config) and now it's looking for the auth info in our_database.users which doesn't exist, lol

Comment: As a side note, please do not use `php artisan config:cache` when developing, this will cause more trouble than it's worth because any changes to your config file and/or `.env` needs that command to re-run which you will forget.